# Django - Is there a remote image field

Tags: django, django-models

I was wondering if there is a field (A model field) that represents a **remote image**.

What I need is to add an image field to my model that isn't stored locally, but is given a remote URL and can only be viewed, not edited or uploaded.

**Edit:** To make myself more clear, I meant I need a field such as URLField that can store a URL (to the image) but that in the admin page, (or other forms) it will show the image like ImageField does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has a [file storage API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/files/storage/). The default storage class is the `FileSystemStorage`, that stores your images using the file system.

One of the best things about Django is its huge ecosystem: you can find storage classes for [S3](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) and other popular hosting services.

It is somewhat easy to write your own, also.

Comment: Does this mean I can write a `ImageField` - like field that uses a storage other than `FileSystemStorage`? (Also, is there a storage for remote images?)

Comment: Yes, for example you could write a storage class that uses paramiko to store images on another host using SSH. See https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/master/storages/backends/sftpstorage.py

Answer (score 2):

A [`URLField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#urlfield) is an extension of the `CharField` and can store a valid URL that points to an image. Note that you will not be able to upload an image, only reference an image that already exists on the web.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    remote_image = models.URLField()
```

In your view you can set the remote image with a string:

```
my_instance = MyModel()
my_instance.remote_image = 'http://example.com/images/example.jpg'
my_instance.save()
```

You can display the remote image in your template by setting the `src` attribute:

```
<img src="{{ my_instance.remote_image }}">
```

Comment: Is there a way to make Django to automatically show a thumbnail of the image in form fields and the admin page, like `ImageField` does?

Comment: You would need to replace the `widget` but that's a whole new question for SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use URLField to store the source URL and handle viewing the image a django View that you build, I can imagine that your django View can read data using your model (including the image source URL), set it in context dictionary object, which can be read from the HTML template of your view to display the image.

Please read about django Views and Templates for more info.

Comment: Please update your answer with links to the relevant documentation you're recommending. Try including an example of the URLField in use.

Comment: Is there a way to make Django to automatically show a thumbnail of the image in form fields and the admin page, like `ImageField` does?

Comment: You would need to replace the `widget` but that's a whole new question for SO.